# URL Forwarded instead of Masked with AWS S3 Static Site via Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

When using Route 53 to have an A Record w/ Alias pointing to an S3 Static Site, the domain forwards to the S3 url rather than masks it.

When i enter:
example.com

I expect it to show the index.html page in my bucket.

Instead, it forwards me to:
example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

I have followed these instructions several times, but always get the same result. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

The site loads fine when viewed through the S3 url at example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com. And Route 53 knows that I want example.com to show the contents of that bucket, but I am just missing something. Why does it redirect?

Comment: Make sure it's an A Alias record in Route53. Can you share a screenshot of your settings?

Comment: I think we've seen this before.  In the second bucket, under `Static Website Hosting`, when you select `Redirect all requests to another host name`... that should *not* be the endpoint (ending in .amazonaws.com) of the other bucket.  It should only be the hostname used in Route 53 for the other bucket.  (You created 2 buckets, right?)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks! That was it exactly. The www.example.com bucket was pointed at the S3 endpoint; it is not just pointed at example.com. I have a tough time wrapping my head around why that mattered, but I'm happy it is working now. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like your browser might have been hitting www.example.com instead of example.com, even though according to the question, you typed in "example.com."  Not sure why a browser would do that -- sounds like a classic case of unhelpful helpfulness -- though I have heard anecdotal evidence of it happening.  I use a [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-headers/mhbpoeinkhpajikalhfpjjafpfgjnmgk) with Chrome that allows easy access to the chain of request/response headers, very useful for a situation like this. (No affiliation with the author of the plugin -- it's just cool).

Comment: I actually was using that plugin already. It was giving me a 301 from example.com to  example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com. When I fixed the issue on the www.example.com bucket as you suggested it works as expected now.