# Clean URLs For Amazon S3 Bucket Contents Using Route 53 Alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, url-routing, amazon-route53

I am currently building a static website for a small startup and decided to us S3 to host it, and have the Domain registered through Route 53.

I have already setup the Bucket as `mysite.net` within S3, populated by index (I have it is as `main.html`) and error document. The `main.html` is within a folder called **main** so I setup a Website Redirect Location Metadata rule that pointed to the full S3 URL where it is located (`https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mysite.net/main/main.html`).

All of the content has been Made Public, I have my Bucket Policy set up as:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mysite.net/*"
    }
]
```

}

And all should be ready to go. In Route 53 I have the Domain successfully registered for the last few days, with the hosted zone for `mysite.net` already created, and I have set up an "A Record" IPV4 Alias pointing to the bucket address within S3.

When I got to type in `mysite.net` in the address bar I get sent to my `error.html` document, which is better than a 403 - but when I click the `Home` tab within that document it leads me to my S3 bucket as `https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mysite.net/main/main.html`

My question is two fold:

**1) What did I do wrong for `mysite.net` to continually redirect to `error.html`**

**2) How can I ensure I will have Clean URLs throughout - it will look unprofessional if I can go to `mysite.net` pull up the main page, then click the *Contact* tab and get send to `https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mysite.net/contact/contact.html`**

I have read [Site domain redirecting to the url of amazon web services bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38704412/site-domain-redirecting-to-the-url-of-amazon-web-services-bucket) as well as [URL Forwarded instead of Masked with AWS S3 Static Site via Route 53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35882347/url-forwarded-instead-of-masked-with-aws-s3-static-site-via-route-53?rq=1) to no avail, and have combed over the S3/Route 53 Docs for static hosting and still am having issues.

Comment: If you directly access `https://mysite .net/main/main.html`, does it work as expected? How about `https://mysite .net/main.html`? Did you configure Route 53 with the `Alias = Yes` option? If your bucket name **exactly** the same as your domain name?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - When I go directly to `https://mysite. net/main/main.html` I get a display error - only http works, but then it resolves into `https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws. com/mysite.net/main/main.html` which is what I do **not** want. Within Route 53 when I have the `Alias = Yes` it pulls mysite.net(S3 bucket) in the drop down, but when I click on it, the alias turns into `s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws. com` - any reason for this?

Comment: Put simply... if everything is configured correctly, then the URL should remain as `mysite.net`. However, there's a chance that the redirection for your `main` page is causing it some problems. In what situation is it working **correctly**? For example, does HTTP directly to a page (without redirect) work as desired?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it does not - which concerns me `mysite.net` as I said goes to `error.html` but clicking the **home** tab redirects me as desired to `main.html` granted - it doesn't present a clean URL, only the elongated `amazon-s3-[...]` type address. The internal endpoint is also redirecting to `error.html` but on my Test buckets the metadata redirection schema works properly, granted they are not tied with a Route 53 Policy Record, not sure what else to troubleshoot

Comment: I would recommend doing a "clean install" and figuring out where your setup varies: Create a new S3 bucket based on a subdomain, eg `test.mysite.net`. Turn on Static Website Hosting. Create a Route 53 domain and points it to the bucket via `Alias=Yes`. Configure the Index and error pages but DO NOT do any redirections. Confirm that it is working as expected, then compare the differences against your existing setup. Trust me... normally it *does* only show a 'clean' custom URL and index pages *do* work.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I think my problem is I am using the folders as a hierarchal structure when S3 treats them as objects. I am doing it to avoid having 50 or so objects on the screen - if I wanted a folder structure how would it change my actual link paths in .html? I want the clean url to actually have paths...like photos/photo1.jpg

Comment: You are welcome to use paths with S3. However, I suggest you get it working without redirects first to make sure your Route 53 configuration is working as desired. Then, try to figure out what changes have caused problems in your current configuration.